# How to deploy a contract using metamask and the callback?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, metamask

I'm trying to deploy a new contract with metamask (in my javascript frontend app). The problem is that, when the receipt is returned, the address is "undefined" since, I suppose, the transaction is not already mined and so the address not exists yet. The deploying result is:

```
Contract {_eth: Eth, transactionHash: 
"0x9e3866f52f274874d96bf60932c03d9849ccdb2cef97c010d6b84c5b529768de", 
 address: undefined, abi: Array(22)}
 abi:(22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 address: undefined
 transactionHash :"0x9e3866f52f274874d96bf60932c03d9849ccdb2cef97c010d6b84c5b529768de"
 _eth: Eth {_requestManager: RequestManager, getBalance: ƒ, getStorageAt: ƒ, getCode: ƒ, getBlock: ƒ, …}
 __proto__:Object
```

Moreover, if I try to access to the `mining` state into `_eth > mining` the output is:

```
[Exception: Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_mining without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async
```

The Javascript code is:

```
deployContent = (name, author, genre, cost) => {
  return new Promise((succ, rej) => {
   this.web3.eth.contract(Content.abi).new(name, author, genre, cost, {gas: 400000}, 
    (err, res) => {if(!err)succ(res); else rej(err);});
  })
}

deployAndPublish = async (name, author, genre, cost) => {
    let contRes = await this.deployContent(name, author, genre, cost);
    console.log(contRes);
    console.log(contRes.address);
    // I need the address here in order to push it into an array
}
```

Any idea how to wait for the address?

Comment: With ethers is really easy https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory-deploy

Answer (score 0):

you can always use an event listener for that. here is a proper example:
https://medium.com/@marcusmolchany/the-easiest-way-to-deploy-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-65f69ac9a627

Comment: You can also use Remix to deploy your contract.

Comment: The problem is that the constructor parameters are read from the UI

Comment: Moreover, I cannot watch an event if I don't know the address...

Comment: oh I see what you mean. You can get the transaction hash and the contract address after the deployment using web3js functions.

Comment: Yes, I get the transaction receipt but the address is undefined (not already mined)

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy and here is another example of the interactions and how it's done. please tell me what framework are you using and íf you are designing an API with node and web3 then you can use solcjs for compiling and deploying!

Comment: I'm Developing a frontend with react, that runs in a browser using metamask injection. The web3 version is 0.20

Comment: I had similar issues when I started months ago and web3js docs are very helpful but I strongly recommend you to check other projects on GitHub to find know-how answers. Please check this answer 
 [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36779/get-transaction-hash-and-mined-receipt/36782)