# How can we get other transactions result like using window.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt on our own transaction?

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain

If I send a transaction, I can watch the result using `window.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` like this:

```
tradeContract.methods.test(...args).send({
  from: pubData.user.address,
  gas: gasAmount
})
  .then(res => {
    let txId = res.transactionHash
    let isSuccess
    window.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txId).then(transReceipt => {
      if (transReceipt) {
        isSuccess = transReceipt.status === '0x1'
        if (isSuccess) {
         // do something if transactions success
        } else {
       // do something if transactions fail
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

However, if I listen to the Transfer event of the contract

```
listenContract.events.Transfer({}, (er, data) => {
  let txId = data.transactionHash
  window.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txId).then(transReceipt => {
    // always return null because the transaction is pending
    console.log('transReceipt', transReceipt)
  })
})
```

`transReceipt` is always null because the transaction is pending. So, in this case, do we have to poll until the transaction finish? Does web3.js has some API can do it like the code on top? I didn't find it. I do find a lot of poll solution like:

[Get Transaction Hash And Mined Receipt](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36779/get-transaction-hash-and-mined-receipt/46406)