# problem of call() returns null

Tags: web3js, truffle, nodejs, ganache

```
contract permission{
struct transaction {
        address payable sender;
        address receiver;
        string datatype;
        Status status;
    }

function getTransactionCount() public view returns(uint256 cnt) {
        uint256 len = transactions.length;
        return(len);
    }
}
```

the above solidty code returns the count of transactions in a contract.
The data insertion(or transaction creation works fine). I get the transactionhash, as it verified but when I call the function to use the above function the `contractInstance.methods.getTransactionCount().call();`
returns null not default 0, even after inserting and using async/await procedure the problem still persists.
Please help 
I have attached the test code for clarity

```
var Web3 = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:8545')

json = require('./../../../build/contracts/permission.json');

const interface = json['abi'];
const bytecode = json['bytecode'];


async function setup(){
    var contract =  new web3.eth.Contract(interface,'0xBcf2D22144C11C20B31A7Aa84875414B252a92DB');
    const accounts = await  web3.eth.getAccounts().then(res=>{return res;})
    const admin = accounts[9];
    var receiver = accounts[1];
    var sender = accounts[3];
    const xl = contract.deploy({ data: bytecode })
    const bb = xl.send({from: admin,gas: 4712388,gasPrice: 100000000000},(error,transactionHash)=>{console.log('w',error,transactionHash);}).then(inst=>{return inst}).catch(err=>{console.log});
    const bl = contract.methods.newTransact(receiver, 'dob').send({from: sender},(error,transactionHash)=>{console.log('e',error,transactionHash);});
    const br = await contract.methods.getTransactionCount().call().then(rlt=>{console.log(rlt)})
    const bt = contract.methods.newTransact(receiver, 'aadhar').send({from: sender},(error,transactionHash)=>{console.log('r',error,transactionHash)}).then(con=>{console.log});
    const by = await contract.methods.getTransactionCount().call().then(rlt=>{console.log(rlt)});

     console.log(br.cnt,by.cnt);
}
setup();
```

Still returns `null,null` as the output.

If await is not used then the code just waits endlessly[image: sample output]

the  following is a sample code that has the same issue as my smart contract(it is just too long for publishing here) but here too the same issue occurs.

```
var Web3 = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:8545')

json = require('./build/contracts/test.json');

const abi = json['abi'];
const bytecode = json['bytecode'];


async function setup(){
    const contract =  new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
    const accounts = await  web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const admin = accounts[9];
    const receiver = accounts[1];
    const sender = accounts[3];

    const deployedContract = await contract.deploy({ data: bytecode }).send({from: admin,gas: 4712388,gasPrice: 100000000000});
    const receipt =  await deployedContract.methods.setData('dob').send({from: sender});

    const data = await deployedContract.methods.getData.call();
    console.log(data);
}
setup();
```

the solidity code the same is :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract test{
    string data;
    function getData() view external returns(string memory){
    return data;
    }
    function setData(string calldata _data) external{
    data = _data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solidity code looks messy. 1. What is `transactions`? 2. What is `cnt` used for?

Comment: Your Javascript code also looks messy. You can use `await` and you can use `then`, but you should not be using both.

Comment: `
struct transaction {
        address payable sender;
        address receiver;
        string datatype;
        Status status;
    }
`
this is to count the number of transactions in the network.
without the await the code just waits endlessly.

Comment: So get rid of the `then`.

Comment: @goodvibration, without then the value returned is null.

Comment: With `const br = await contract.methods.getTransactionCount().call()`, the value of `br` is `null`? Are you sure?

Comment: yes positive i just double checked it

Comment: @vaishakhk Since it returns null and you do not wait for the contract deployment so it is possible the contract didn't deploy on time or it was incorrectly deployed. What is bytecode beginning? ie it does start with '0x..'?

Comment: Maybe there's a problem in the `transactions` array declaration? Could you post both the declaration of `transactions` and the function that creates a new transaction (struct) instance?

Answer (score 1):

> I get the transactionhash, as it verified

I believe you are mistaken about this. The returned value from `...newTransact()` is a transaction hash. This is an *acknowledgment* that the transaction was *submitted*, not a confirmation that it was mined. That transaction will hang around in the transaction pool for a little while before it is included in a block.

The code suggests that you do not wait for the transaction to be mined. Right here:

```
const bl = contract.methods.newTransact(receiver, 'dob').send({from: sender},(error,transactionHash)=>{console.log('e',error,transactionHash);});
const br = await contract.methods.getTransactionCount().call().then(rlt=>{console.log(rlt)})
```

Have a look over here to get a sense of what has to happen between those steps: [Get Transaction Hash And Mined Receipt](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36779/get-transaction-hash-and-mined-receipt)

Hope it helps.